# Heads Up Notification for Android KitKat (API 19)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, heads-up-notifications

Is there anyway to implement `Heads Up Notification` for `Android Kitkat (API 19)`?

Based on my findings as below link, it says that heads up notification can be disabled in android Kitkat.

http://teckfront.com/enable-heads-notifications-android-4-4-4-kitkat-take-quick-peek/

But based on documentation from google, this function implemented on android 5.0+ 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up

Appreciate that if anyone could provide me guidance on how to implement it for `Android Kitkat` version

thanks

Comment: I don't think it came in all devices or builds. Maybe it was device manufacturer specific. Read the comments in the article link you have provided..

Comment: I've found something like App: Floatify that could perform something like before Android L. too bad i can't seems to find the source code for it. :(